# rice wine brewing stuck

Tags: wine, sake

I am trying to make glutonous rice wine, purchased the "Angel rice yeast (amalyze)" from asian market, the "white cookie/powder" broke rice down into sugar.

I have measured, it is 40%, very sweet to taste. But it just does not ferment. The sweetness always there, does not reduce.
The liquid pools out is very sweet. .does that means it has being converted from starch to sugar already ?

I tried to pitch the champage yeast into it, it only last 2 days, before bubbles stopped. Why?

Is it too sweet (40%Brix) for champage yeast?

Thanks

Comment: But if you went down the Asian market, why didn't you buy real rice wine yeast?

Comment: @Robert One can no longer trust what you get from store.. especially item from china. To use for health, one must know how to make it himself.  This world is no longer as safe and friendly as it used to be.  Time changed, world changed, men's heart changed.

Comment: You don't trust yeast from china, but you trust fungally produced amylase from China? In fact, depending on the product, your Angel product may have contained live Rhyzopus Oryzae to produce the amylase. (Its safe, don't worry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct, then amylase powder is used to turn rice into sugar?

40° Brix is a gravity of 1.180. Champagne yeast can endure a lot, but starting from this amount of sugar would lead to an ABV of 23.6%, if your yeast could endure that. I find champagne yeasts of 15%.

So yes, your yeast has had a good time, but the alcohol level is too high. I would suggest to dilute your brew with the same amount of boiled and cooled water, add wine nutrition salts, and again some champagne yeast to make sure that your mix is completely fermented.